# NSDictionary count number of keys

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to create an `NSDictionary` of unique keys with each value being the count of the unique keys.

i.e.

Given the array `[apple, apple, banana, apple, pear, banana]` I'd get the dictionary...

```
{
    apple : 3,
    banana : 2,
    pear : 1
}
```

I'm sure I've seen code before where you can do something like...

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueKeys = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *string in myArray) {
    uniqueKeys[string]++;
}
```

But I can't remember what the exact syntax is.

I know I could do it long hand by extracting the `NSNumber` and changing it and putting it back but I wanted to use this method if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you may be able to use NSCountedSet.
If "apple" and "apple" are equal, you'll be able to know both how many "fruits" are in your counted-set as well as how many "apple"s are in the set.

Apple's Documentation:

> The NSCountedSet class declares the programmatic interface to a
>   mutable, unordered collection of indistinct objects. A counted set is
>   also known as a bag.
>
> Each distinct object inserted into an NSCountedSet object has a
>   counter associated with it. NSCountedSetkeeps track of the number of
>   times objects are inserted and requires that objects be removed the
>   same number of times. Thus, there is only one instance of an object in
>   an NSSet object even if the object has been added to the set multiple
>   times. The count method defined by the superclass NSSet has special
>   significance; it returns the number of distinct objects, not the total
>   number of times objects are represented in the set. The NSSet and
>   NSMutableSet classes are provided for static and dynamic sets
>   (respectively) whose elements are distinct.

**Update**

Here is an example:

```
NSCountedSet * fruits = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:@[@"apple", @"apple", @"banana", @"apple", @"pear", @"banana"]];
NSLog(@"fruit count = %d", [fruits count]);
NSLog(@"num apples = %d", [fruits countForObject:@"apple"]);
NSLog(@"num bananas = %d", [fruits countForObject:@"banana"]);
NSLog(@"num pears = %d", [fruits countForObject:@"pear"]);
NSLog(@"num oranges = %d", [fruits countForObject:@"orange"]);
```

Which will output:

```
2013-02-02 13:07:59.058 test[46614:c07] fruit count = 3
2013-02-02 13:07:59.059 test[46614:c07] num apples = 3
2013-02-02 13:07:59.062 test[46614:c07] num bananas = 2
2013-02-02 13:07:59.062 test[46614:c07] num pears = 1
2013-02-02 13:07:59.063 test[46614:c07] num oranges = 0
```

Comment: Hmm... that looks perfect. Will have a go at using it.

Answer (score 1):

NSCountedSet delivers a really elegant solution, but if anyone for any reason need a dictionary rather than a set it's not *that* much of a hassle to create this "long hand". (It might me useful if you need to traverse all keys and values in one go for instance).

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryWithKeysAndNumbers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in keysArray) {
    if ([dictionaryWithKeysAndNumbers valueForKey:key]) {
        NSNumber *numberOfKeyInstances = [dictionaryWithKeysAndNumbers valueForKey:key];
        NSInteger newValue = numberOfKeyInstances.intValue +1;
        [dictionaryWithKeysAndNumbers setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newValue] forKey:key];
    }
    else{
        [dictionaryWithKeysAndNumbers setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:key];
    }
}
```